# pygame- place picture in random location on the screen

Tags: python, random, position, pygame

I will explain some of the program.
I am trying to make a snake game.
My problem is that the snake is always starting in the corner of the screen which is the place where the snake is supposed to die..
I want to place "image" (image is the name of the photo) in randon location on the screen.
How can I do it? I tried few times but the progran has been stuck...
here is the code..

```
  import sys, pygame,time
  FPS=30
  fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()
  window_size = ( 819, 460 )

  white = ( 255, 255, 255 )
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode( window_size )


  move = (0,0) # init movement

  done = False

  image = pygame.image.load( 'snikebodydraw.png')
  image1 = pygame.image.load( 'deadarea.png')
  screen.blit( image, (100,100) )
  rect = image.get_rect()


  while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:


        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
          move = (-10, 0 )
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
          move = ( 10, 0 )
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
          move = ( 0,-10 )
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
          move = ( 0, 10 )

    rect = rect.move(move)

    screen.blit(image1, (0,0))
    screen.blit( image, rect )
```

More information:
    http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=zlznmy3imumj.png

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.display` assumes the location (0,0) of the display to be the left upper corner, so probably when you position your image you are doing it at position (0,0). You should check the position you have in `player.rect` is not (0,0) when calling at:

```
  screen.blit( player.image, player.rect )
```

If you would like to position `image` at a random position of the screen you could generate two random numbers (the `x` and the `y`) with the `random` library and pass them to the second argument of blit, as for example in your case (taking into account that your display size is 819x460):

```
  screen.blit( player.image, (random.randint(0,819),random.randint(0,460)) )
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to start with the position (100,100) I think that you have a problem with your variable `rect` because the line `rect = image.get_rect()` on your code returns `rect=(0,0,50,50)` which I think are the left upper corner and the right bottom corner of your image. So, when you execute later `rect = rect.move(move)` the two first values of rect are (0,0) which are passed to `blit()` then your image goes back to position (0,0) in the first iteration fo your loop.

A possible solution is to add `rect = rect.move(100,100)` below your `rect = image.get_rect()`, before entering the loop. This will make it as overwrites the initial (0,0) values, just like this:

```
rect = image.get_rect()
rect = rect.move(100,100)
```

Try to fix that and you will have your problem solved.

You have to take into account also that when you do `blit()`, usually the point of that image that you position is the left upper corner of the image.
For example, if you do:

```
# To center the point (0,0) of the image at the location (0,0) of the screen
screen.blit(image,(0,0))
# To center the point (0,0) of the image at the location (100,100) of the screen
screen.blit(image,(100,100))
```

So take it into account when positioning your image as well.

Comment: i edited the post... its still not working for me.. i will do the random later, its not a problem. but how i can do that the snake will start from position (100,100)?

Comment: You should have a line `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` within your while loop (after calling `blit()`) to update on the display the new positions. If you do not have these you don't see the changes on the display.

Comment: i put a link of a picture of the code with the program starting. you can see it at the end of the code

Comment: I tried your code by inserting `pygame.display.update()` right after `screen.blit(image,(100,100))` and my image is shown at position (100,100). This should work for you to start at (100,100).

Comment: See above my answer update with the problem with your code.

Comment: Take a look on the picture that I uploaded. You can see that I did exactly like you have done. But its not working.

Comment: You haven't changed the `rect = rect.move(move)` line within your loop. Please read my entire answer update. You have to modify that for your code to work. That line is drawing your image back into position (0,0) in the first loop iteration.

Comment: OK, I've got it. No need to modify `rect = rect.move(move)`. A possible solution is to add `rect = rect.move(100,100)` below your `rect = image.get_rect()`. This will make it as overwrites the initial (0,0) values. I got it working on my laptop. Updated above.

Comment: @user5194010 Did you go make it work with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

To answer (only) the question of how to choose a random starting position:

```
import random

x = random.randint(0,xmax)
y = random.randint(0,ymax)

screen.blit(player.image, (x,y))
```

Draw the starting configuration once, before you enter the `while` loop, so that you don't have to change your updating procedure.

Comment: i edited the post... its still not working for me.. i will do the random later, its not a problem. but how i can do that the snake will start from position (100,100)?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Try to give a few more details. Also, it would be quite handy, if you could provide the images that you're using. I just tried it with a image myself, and it does appear at the specified location, so this part seems to work.

Comment: i put a link of a picture of the code with the program starting. you can see it at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many people have said in comments, you need `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()` after your blitting. This will update your screen with the image on it.